# .htaccess 301 re-directing .html pages to sitemap.html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've tried 301 redirecting .html pages to sitemap.html in two ways and neither one works.

- I've checked this code over and over again.
- I've used .htaccess checkers/validators and they show no errors.
- The same code works for folder-to-folder re-directs--this only happens for re-directs from .html files to sitemap.html.

**The Problem:**

The pages should be redirected to www.example.com/sitemap.html

Instead they're redirected to www.example.com/sitemap.htmlpage.html

In other words, .htaccess somehow puts the file name after sitemap.html.

*I've used these two methods:*

**1:**

```
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ /sitemap.html$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

In the first one, all the files within the directory should be re-directed to sitemap.html. Note that the index page of the category re-directs fine but the .html ending pages inside it don't.

**2:**

```
redirect 301 /directory/page.html http://www.example.com/sitemap.html
```

I've also tried redirecting each page individually with the same results.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use captured for redirecting everything to `/sitemap.xml`. Just use a rule like this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^directory/ /sitemap.html [R=301,NC,L]
```